# Share SSH on the web

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have my Ubuntu running in my home network. It has no any port forwards from router that shares Internet. I would like to access my Ubuntu to check log files and execute some commands. It would be nice to have SHH. How to achieve that without direct connection? Can I somehow ask Ubuntu to wait for incoming SSH connection somewhere on cloud?

Comment: You can use SSH to access Ubuntu when you are using a device on the same network. You cannot SSH into Ubuntu on your home network from anywhere else without exposing your home network to the internet.  This can be very dangerous. If you have to ask, don't do it.

Comment: I expect to find web service that allows to ssh to device that has registered in it

Comment: You have a few options. You could port-forward, but if you don't know what you're doing, I don't suggest it. I'd require key-based authentication (no passwords). You could get a cheap cloud VM, port forward that, and run Wireguard or something simaler, and tunnel through that. Or, there are pre-made options [such as this one](https://goteleport.com/ssh-server-access/). But honestly, port forwarding and requiring keys might be enough (though you should understand the risk, though).

Comment: I'm using GSM router that has no feature like port forward. Another bad thing is that looks like IP address provided by GSM providers is not on Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for a VPN solution. Wireguard is a popular choice to run; one client runs at home, and one on your laptop (presumably).

There are other products like it, more commercial (tailscale).

A second way would be to add a more legacy solution: run a vpn server on your home router; some vendors of DSL routers do that without effort.

And a third option is to move your logs to somewhere less private than your home: Upload it to the cloud, so you don't need to be at home to see the logs :)